# Hairy $u$-substitution problem

Tags: calculus, integration, trigonometry, definite-integrals

Evaluate using the $u$-substitution:

$$\int_{-1}^{1} \frac{dx}{4 + x^2}.$$

Now, I was told to set
$$\tan u = \frac{x}{2},$$
but that doesn't help me at all. Hints needed!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, the substitution $\tan u = x/2$ is unnecessary because
$$\int \frac{dx}{x^2 + a^2} = \frac{1}{a}\tan^{-1}\left(\frac{x}{a}\right) + C$$
is a well-known result.
In your case $a = 2$.

However, if you insist, using the substitution $\tan u = x/a$, we can actually derive the formula above. To this end, we proceed as follows.

Say $x = a\tan u$. Then $dx/du = a \sec^2 u$ and $u = \tan^{-1}(x/a)$, so
$$\int \frac{dx}{x^2 + a^2} = \int \frac{a \sec^2 u}{a^2(1 + \tan^2 u)} du = \int \frac{du}{a} = \frac{1}{a}\tan^{-1}\left(\frac{x}{a}\right) + C.$$
Notice that I used the identity $1 + \tan^2 u = \sec^2 u.$

Comment: How do you get that?

Comment: @Paze I edited my answer. I hope it helps.

Comment: Small comment, it might be clearer to write that the substitution is $\tan{u}=x/a$ rather than $\tan{u}=x/2$, since your answer is given in the general form.

Comment: @oLas Yes, that was a typo. Thanks.